# Spread syntax for complex objects

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax, ecmascript-2018

Assume I have an object like this

```
let store = {
  "articles": [{...}, {...}, ...],
  "errors": { "p1": { "myNewObject":0 }, "p2": {...}, ...}
}
```

I want to take advantage of [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to return a clone of this object where `store.errors.p1` is a new object. Is the following the simplest way?

```
let newStore = { ...store, ...{ errors: { ...store.errors, p1: { "myNewObject":1 } } } }
```

Comment: Yes, it is. ---

Comment: @x539, no it's not, the spread and brackets around `errors` can be removed

Comment: @jo_va your right, must have overseen that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not the simplest syntax to clone your store and do a deep copy of `p1`, but it's very close:

```
let newStore = { ...store, ...{ errors: { ...store.errors, p1: { myNewObject: 1 } } } }
//                         ^^^^                                                     ^
//                           |_______ not necessary ________________________________|
```

You can remove the extra spread and brackets around `errors`.

```js
const store = { articles: [{ a: 1 }], errors: { p1: { myNewObject: 0 }, p2: { a: 1 } } }

const newStore = { ...store, errors: { ...store.errors, p1: { myNewObject: 1 } } }

console.log(JSON.stringify(store))
console.log(JSON.stringify(newStore))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something as [lodash.clonedeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep) an then just change that property with `store.errors.p1 = { "myNewObject": 1}`.

Or if you want, you could create a function `assocIn` (inspired by clojue) that does it in a more idiomatic way:

```
const assocIn = (obj, [key, ...rest], value) => 
    ({...obj, [key]: rest.length == 0 ? value : assocIn(obj[key], rest, value)});
store = assocIn(store, ['errors', 'p1'], { "myNewObject": 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you feel this is not readable then you could use a `reduce` to iterate over `errors` object and update the object first and then use spread syntax. It might be a bit more lines of code but will offset for readability.

```js
const updatedkey = "p1";
const updatedData = {
  "myNewObject": 1
};
const store = {
  "articles": [{
    ...
  }, {
    ...
  }],
  "errors": {
    "p1": {
      "myNewObject": 0
    },
    "p2": {
      ...
    },
  }
};
const updatedErrors = Object.keys(store.errors).reduce((acc, key) => {
  const acc[key] = store.errors[key];

  if (key === updatedkey) {
    acc[key] = {
      ...acc[key],
      ...updatedData
    }
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

const newStore = {
  ...store,
  errors: updatedErrors
};
```